# Retrieving specific data nested under push keys in Firebase Database

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Situation**:  I'm trying to retrieve a string from the key "title" under the first push key (most recent object) inside my [Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIKEW.jpg), but I keep getting "null".

*MainActivity.java*

```
    ...
    mDatabaseReference.limitToFirst(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ExecutiveOrder executiveOrder = snapshot.getValue(ExecutiveOrder.class);
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Title: " + executiveOrder.getTitle());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("Executive Order", "The read failed: " + databaseError.getDetails());
        }
    });
    ...
```

*ExecutiveOrder.java*

```
package com.example.cleeg.part;

import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class ExecutiveOrder {

private String mTitle;
private String mDate;
private String mSummary;
private String mText;

// Default constructor
public ExecutiveOrder() {}

public ExecutiveOrder(String title, String date, String text) {
    mTitle = title;
    mDate = date;
    mText = text;
}

public String getTitle() { return mTitle; }
public String getDate() { return mDate; }
public String getSummary() { return mSummary; }
public String getText() { return mText; }
}
```

**UPDATE**: The problem was that I didn't have setters in my ExecutiveOrder.java

Comment: add your database structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of changes to be done. It worked fine to me on very similar DB structure:

1. mDatabaseReference definition should not include "Executive Branch", because the branch is actually the value to be returned as object 
   of executiveOrder
2. I would recommend to change ValueEventListener to ChildEventListener, and update @Override methods accordingly (the names of the methods are slightly different).

I updated you code with needed changes - it should work. Please try. Well... as I can't test it on exact same DB, it may include couple of typos. Apologize if so. But it worked on very similar DB.

```
mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    ChildEventListener recentListener = new ChildEventListener() {


           @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
ExecutiveOrder executiveOrder = ds1.getValue(ExecutiveOrder.class);
            String title = executiveOrder.getTitle();
            Log.i("MainActivity", "Title: " + title);                        

                    }
                }
            }



            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        }

        };
        mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(recentListener);
```

Comment: Additional info - if the query returns more than one object, but you need specifically the latest one - please consider  adding timestamp to the data structure.

Comment: Can you please add implementation of ExecutiveOrder class? Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure ExecutiveOrder has default constructor without args.

Comment: I'll see in next half an hour...
Meantime also check security rules for you DB
For testing purposes only consider to set them as public:
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: They've been set to public already.  :)  Thanks for your continued help btw

Comment: Wait... I see there are no setters in ExecutiveOrder ... only getters. I think this is a reason. Please add them and try again.

Comment: Fine, I'm glad to know it helps! 
The mechanism of creating the object by firebase (in couple of words) is: it first creates the empty object - that's why empty constructor is needed. And then it "fills" all matched fields (i.e. name of the fields of the class should match the fields in the firebase DB and names of setters  should follow the naming convention). If proper setters aren't found - the object remains "empty" and, you get null when try to retrieve the data.

Comment: BTW... if you liked the answer - you are welcome to upvote ;)

Comment: I did, but since I have less than 15 reputation, it doesn't change the publicly displayed post score. :( It is recorded though.

Comment: Thanks! Have a nice day!

Comment: BTW.... I see now case on my side, where similar mechanism is working without setters. But, the difference from your case is - the general number of fields, they names, and parameters of non_default constructor are still fully matching. While in your case, field mSummary is found in the class, but is not found at firebase DB. Probably, firebase uses more complex heuristics to build the objects from the DB, and can recognize more complex things.  But, as soon as Java and firebase are completely different systems, the general recommendation is to keep the things fully matched ))

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between variable names of the class and the corresponding database entries. The key in the database has the name "title" whereas you declare it as "mTitle" in your ExecutiveOrder.java class. Therefore, you are getting 'null'. Change the variable names in your ExecutiveOrder.java to match the "key" names exactly in the database and it should work fine.

All the best!!

Comment: I don't think this is the case...I changed all my variables to match the "key" names and it works, but when I comment out all my setters, I get null

Comment: Setters are not mandatory for uploading or downloading information from Firebase. Only 3 things are mandatory - an empty default constructor, all getter methods and "key" and "attributes" having same name and type. But if it is working fine, then there is more than what is visible in your code above.... All the best, anyway...